Python get current keyboard / input device
I want to create a python script to read the keyboard input of one of my old keyboards and converts the input into a macro output.
All i managed to do is reading the Input of either all devices connected or none.
Is there a way to determine which keyboard is currently typing?
I tried using win32api but since I am not that familiar with the win api I haven't gotten any further.
Also I found several solutions for Linux but since I am on Windows...
As I was trying to get it done with the hid library I couldn't read the input from my keyboards.
Hopefully somebody can help.
